# Dynamically changing parameter based on another in an SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

We have a report that in 2005 version of SSRS, we could dynamically update one parameter (which is a text box) from another report parameter (which is a drop down).  Each time the drop down changes, the text box would update.  No problem.  Now in 2008, it only happens when we first preview the report (in other words, the text box is updated by the drop down).  If I change the textbox to a drop down, it works.  But if I change it back to a text box (i.e. I no longer set Available Values to none), the text box only updates when first previewed.

Has anyone had this issue before?    Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2008 SSRS doesn't always update every parameter on a report any longer if it doesn't appear to be necessary.  There is a property under the parameter Advanced --> Refresh data when the parameter changes.  The default value is "Automatically determine when to refresh".  For your situation you probably need to change the parameter property to "Always refresh".